# How do you digitize an ROI in envi 5.2?

Tags: remote-sensing, envi

Is there a way to digitize an ROI in ENVI 5.2 that is larger than the area shown in the viewer?  I'm setting up labs for an intro to RS class, and the next step is to subset the image to get rid of the edge pixels.  As far as I can tell, the ROI tool in the new ENVI doesn't allow you to pan your view and keep digitizing, which means that you can't get an ROI that is larger than whatever subset of the image you are looking at...I hope I'm describing this problem well enough, let me know if it's unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enoying that `Pan`
 doesn't work anymore during digitizing. A workaround for the problem is:

Zoom out of the image using the mouse wheel until you see your entire image, then move your arrow to the area where you want to continue your digitizing (but don't click) and zoom in again using the mouse wheel.

Comment: Thanks for that, that works well.  I've also found you can (sort of) digitize an ROI in parts. However, using the wheel is a lot easier.